# count then divide by a variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to count first then divide by variable and then multiply by 100.  For instance, my variable is 16 the the total_count is 15 then i expect to see 93.75, that is 15/16*100.  Something is not right with my calculation.

```
declare @myVar int
set @myVar = 16
  select  S.FAC_ID, NAME, COUNT(TTL_COUNT)/@myVar*100 AS FINAL_RESULT
  from MYTABLE
   GROUP BY S.FAC_ID, NAME
```

Comment: i understood you expect 93.75, but what is the value you get?

Comment: It may appear a little dumb, but, you are not dividing by 100...
You need this `(COUNT(TIL_COUNT))/@MyVar)/100`

Comment: sorry, i was suppose to multiply by 100 and i just updated my post.

Comment: Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally.

Comment: @JackMarchetti does PEMDAS apply here? Wouldn't SQL work left to right anyways, which would be 15/16 = .9375 * 100 = 93.75?

Comment: @shadowjfaith `15/16` will result `0`, try `select 15/16, 15/16.00` to see both results...

Comment: @JackMarchetti That is an issue with data type not PEMDAS.

Comment: Really? I thought SQL abided by PEMDAS

Comment: @JackMarchetti It does, but as with basic computing math all calculations are processed from left to right unless otherwise stated by PEMDAS.

Comment: Right so the way his SQL is written would be: TTL_COUNT/1600

Comment: @JackMarchetti MD and AS are processed at the same time left to right not M first then D. MD carry the same weight and AS carry the same weight. Please refer to http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100812185048AAnYnP1

Comment: Bad source, but best I could find on short time due to cooking dinner.

Comment: @aledpardo Please follow your advice and google PEMDAS as you will find this equation would have been processed correctly if data types were correct.

Comment: @shadowjfaith yes, you're right, I suggested use parenthesis as it's visible what I'm waiting for the calculation, because, sometimes we need to stop and think what's PEMDAS sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
COUNT(TTL_COUNT)*100/@myVar
```

That should be the right calculation

And as pointed out it should be either double or float

```
declare @myVar double
```

Comment: @moe If this solved your issue please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your variable to be a float or other type with a decimal point.  SQL Server does integer division by default:

```
declare @myVar float;
set @myVar = 16;
select  S.FAC_ID, NAME, COUNT(TTL_COUNT)/@myVar AS FINAL_RESULT
from MYTABLE
group by S.FAC_ID, NAME;
```

If you want the multiplication by 100:

```
select  S.FAC_ID, NAME, 100*COUNT(TTL_COUNT)/@myVar AS FINAL_RESULT
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable data type is wrong.
Try this:

```
declare @myVar decimal(28,2);
set @myVar = 16.00;
  select  S.FAC_ID, NAME
       , ( COUNT( TTL_COUNT ) / @myVar ) * 100 AS FINAL_RESULT
    from MYTABLE
   group by S.FAC_ID, NAME
```

When you divide `15/16` SQL Server (and any other programming environment, it's a math rule) assumes you are expecting an `integer` as result, it explains your `0`. To get the decimal result, your divisor must be floating point.